# Meromorphic Function (Polynomial) in the $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ has pole in $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

1) I want to show that a meromorphic polynomial $f\in \mathbb{C}[z]$ on $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ has a pole in $\infty$ and

2) I want to know where I can read off the pole order.

1) Maybe I can write $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_nz^n$ and then show that $ \lim_{z\to \infty} |f(z)| = \infty$ but don't know how..?

2) I think I can read the pole order from the degree of the polynomial, but this I can only do if the function is homogeneous.

So all in all I'm standing with the back to the wall. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** : Let's do the change of variable $w = \frac{1}{z}$. Now, $w=0$ correspond to $\infty$ and the Laurent serie of $f(w) = f(1/z)$ around $0$ is $f(w) = \sum_k a_k w^{-k}$. Can you finish from here ?

Comment: Now I would say that \begin{align*} \lim_{z\to\infty} |f(z)| &= \lim_{w\to 0} |f(w)| =\left\vert \sum_{k=0}^n a_k w^{-k} \right\vert = \lim_{w\to 0} \sum_k |a_k| \left\vert \frac{1}{w^k} \right\vert = \infty \end{align*} if $k\neq 0$ is that right?

Comment: The limits is indeed $\infty$ if $n>0$, as the leading term is $a_n w^{-n}$.

Comment: And this also give you the order of the pole ($n$).

Comment: Right, now it's clear! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome !